# How do I estimate downvotes' "efficiency"?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

No, this is not another post to complain about downvotes. Downvotes (like upvotes) are the core of this site and need to be used in the right way.

This said, I am wondering if **I** am downvoting correctly. How efficient are my downvotes?

This may sounds like a philosophical question so let me first define what I mean by *correctly downvoting* or what's is a *good downvote*. For this we need to consider the overal votes and actions done on a post.

First, I will downvote a post based on its content (this is my personal thinking about the post being bad) then more actions will be done to that post and I consider my downvote to be good when:

- The post is deleted (either by the owner or the community) which means that, in fact, it was a bad post.
- The post will end with a negative score (at least `-3`) which means that at least two users agree with me and it's more likely to be a bad post.

But if a post will end with a positive score, I was probably wrong downvoting it.

---

**My question**: is there any way to calculate the number of my *good* downvotes? Is there a way to get the ratio `good downvotes/all downvotes` which will define the "effeciency"? I want to know if such data exist and if we are able to get them?

I first thought about SEDE, but since votes are anonymous I don't think I can get any information there. Checking the profile activity, there is a lot of numbers that may help, but I am not able to find the relation between them.

> [image]

---

> [image]

---

> [image]

Based on what we have in our profile, is there a way to get the information I am looking for? Or at least to approximate it? And what is the relation between all those numbers?

I think that getting the number of downvotes done on a posts with negative score may be tricky, but getting the number of downvotes made on deleted post can probably be easier (we may compare how many `-1` we have versus how many downvotes we have done).

**Is such information really useful?**

Probably not but I am simply curious to know if I can get such information. It may help to get back to old downvotes and retract them in case the post is edited to be a good one which will increase the ratio.

<sup>The above doesn't imply that downvoting a post with a positive score is bad OR upvoting a post with a negative score is also bad. This is a personnal thinking about how I consider a downvote to be *good* and anyone can disagree with. I simply want to know if it's possible to gather the numbers I described. I am not aiming to discuss about how we should consider downvotes which is already done a lot of times.</sup>

---

**UPDATE**

As I suspected, this will be turned to debate about my reasoning which is not the purpose of this question. I am not against this and it's totally legitimate to disagree (or agree) with me and to have a different opinion but let's don't forget the main question: Is there a way to have those data and how do we interpret the numbers I found in my profile?

Comment: My guess is even with all the positive data about votes and voters, your results would be inconclusive, or if conclusive, suspect. You’re going to get a lot of conflation and noise arising from the pile-on effect. People feel more comfortable downvoting when they’ve seen others downvote first: even if you’re the first downvoted, you’ve significantly lowered the barrier to others downvoting after you. If voting were blind, this conflation would be eased. But it’s not, so it ain’t.

Comment: @DanBron I simply want to know the data about *my* downvotes not all the downvotes of other users ... I don't care if what I described is accurate/correct/has a meaning but I want to know if it's possible to have the numbers.

Comment: This seems a bit pointless if you don’t care if the results *mean* anything. I suspect you do want and intend for your results to mean something, but you don’t believe what I wrote above. But hey it’s your time, not mine. No, you can’t get this data from SEDE. You could scrape your own profile page and build up a dataset that way, over time. Or maybe the API can provide it. But again, I believe your results will not give you the conclusions you are saying you want.

Comment: @DanBron I simply don't want this to be considered as a discussion about how we should consider downvoting and debate about if what I said is relevant/accurate or not, etc etc ... Each one will have an opinion on this and for sure it won't be the same. I simply described a situation and I am wondering if there is a way to obtain some data and how all the numbers in my profile can interpreted

Comment: I gave you what answer I had on that. Either scrape your profile over time (using your creds), or explore if the API is willing to give you some data. On the larger topic, I was only trying to save you some time and pain. As I said, it doesn’t effect me, and I’m certainly not going to stand in your way. Also, in case it matters to you, I didn’t downvote you, and I won’t.

Comment: Anybody having 10000 downs and only 1000 ups, should have long left the site, because he thinks it is full of crap. The only remaining possibility that he has an irresistible urge to do so many harm as it is possible.

Comment: @peterh Under that theory, what technique would you recommend to distinguish between the cases “he thinks the site is full of crap (but he loves it and wants to see it thrive)” and “the site is full of crap (but he loves it and wants to see it thrive)”?

Comment: @DanBron Are you really curious, what do I think, how could it be done better?

Comment: @peterh I am really curious, genuinely. I was not being sarcastic or ironic. But not at all in how you think it could be done better. I want to know if you have an objective, useful, and consistent method to distinguish those two cases. It would be enormously useful.

Comment: @DanBron Votes don't give an objective proof about the quality of the posts, they are only a rough signature, how the readers perceive them. Your cases are not disjunct, first is about the view of the voter, the second is about the objective quality. It might be an interesting philosophical question, if the second even exists. However, if an active voter has ten times more downs than ups, it is an objective proof that he thinks the site is full of crap.

Comment: @DanBron But I think it would be a more interesting question,and it could be a really enermously useful development, to find a better approximation of the objective quality of the posts, using the subjective voting data. For that, I have some ideas, unfortunately the secrecy of the votes made my tries practically untestable. But I still have some side results.

Comment: Side note: you are missing “significantly improved after downvote” case...

Comment: "_But if a post will end with a positive score, I was probably wrong downvoting it._"... Oh really? So if we see a post with 10+ upvotes, no one should ever touch the downvote button on it, because it would be wrong to give it a -1?

Comment: @Cœur Reacting [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376525/how-to-estimate-downvotes-efficiency?noredirect=1#comment646121_376525) Btw, in my opinion, a better system would be to make the downvotes stronger, but this 10000 down / 1000 up people should be affected by some special rule (for example, *their* downs could remain -2)

Comment: @Cœur please read the small note at the end of the question ... I never implied such things. I simply described a situation (a personal thinking that I don't want to debate) and my question is to see if there is a way to gather the information I want

Comment: @peterh so you know the meaning of the those numbers then? can you explain me what the 10000 down exactly means? and what the 3000 means? because I didn't make 10000 downvotes and no I won't leave the site.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't miss that case, but given some numbers about what I described I might find those case and probably get back to retract my downvotes in case I find an improved post.

Comment: "But if a post will end with a positive score, I was probably wrong downvoting it.| I don't get your reasoning there. Your statement is like "I do not got to elections, because a single vote cannot change the outcome, anyway". You should express your opinion, without looking at the other votes.

Comment: @allo there is simply no reasoning and no opinion, I am describing some data and I want to know if it's possible to gather them .... 1) Number of downvotes on a post with negative score 2) number of downvotes on a post with positive scrore 3) number of downvotes on a deleted posts ... as a side note: I never look at the other before downvoting/upvoting.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have zero saying here. The SE concept is that they ignore such values. You can check your voting stats on your profile page, here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif?tab=topactivity You have around 11000 downs and around 1600 ups. Well...

Comment: @peterh I know what I have (I have already shared in this question) but as you can see there is also a tab saying that I have 3000 DOWNVOTES and 11k DOWN s(not downvotes) so what DOWNS means? it's including delete vote? close vote? something else?

Comment: You´re implying your own votes won´t have any effect on others, which is - as Dan Bron  already mentioned - whrong. What if you´d downvote on a post first and therefor lower the barrier for others to also downvote? This would give you the impression your downvote was more efficient as others have also downvoted. However those downvotes might not have been cast if you didn´t downvote first.

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, only the downs. Delete vote is a different entity.

Comment: @peterh so why I have different values then? 3000 and 10000?

Comment: @HimBromBeere again I am not implying anything, each on is free to downvote/upvote like he want or based on previous votes, I don't care at all ... I described a set of data and want to know if it's possible to gather it, that's all.

Comment: @TemaniAfif You gave 10214 downvotes and 1601 upvotes.

Comment: Okay, I make it more clear: there´s no way to achive this, because it simply makes no sense, because of the mentioned reasons. Even if there was a way to achieve this data, what would you interpret from it? It simply is not true that it would include only **your** votes, because your votes may affect how other users may vote and thus also affect your own numbers.

Comment: @HimBromBeere numbers don't have any sense until we give them a sense and I am not looking for any sense here. I am looking for data : (1) number of downvotes on deleted question (2) number of downvotes on post with positive score (3) number of downvotes on post with negative score .. etc .. that's it. If we can, how? If we cannot then we cannot.

Comment: @peterh again, I know this, but check *again* the question and what I shared : In my profile there is a section saying I have done 3000 Downvotes so *again* what's is this number if the 10000 is the number of downvotes.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can you post a link where this 3000 downs is visible?

Comment: @peterh it's within this question, not visible on my profile because it's only visible to me ... I shared different screenshot with different values

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think you should split it into two questions. First, if it's possible to find out the "efficiency" of your votes and second, what are the numbers on your profile, because they don't make sense. Most people try to answer the first question and ignore the other or they don't get it and only see, that you have about 6:1 ratio for downvotes, even if it's not true.

Comment: @Triber but there is mainly one question and the numbers on my profile are a part of the research I have done to answer the first one and I was thinking if I can get something from them and to also understand them. Unfortunately, people are focusing on the definition of the "efficiency" I have done which is a simple definition to better describe the data

Comment: @peterh and Temani, the reason for the discrepancy between the "10207 down" and "3878 votes cast" shown on the downvotes tab is that the latter does not include deleted posts. So Temani has cast 10207 downvotes and 7329 (72%) of those posts have then been deleted. This, by the way, to some degree vindicates at least 72% of Temani's downvotes, and highlights the wrongness of assuming that somebody is casting downvotes inappropriately just because they cast lots of them, without  knowing anything about their browsing pattern and how they encounter the content they downvote.

Comment: @MarkAmery finally a comment on what am looking for! From where you get this information? are you sure that the 10207 are all the downvotes and the 3878 are only the non deleted one? if it's the case I have half of my answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I often downvote a question and several of its answers simultaneously. When an answer gets deleted, it gets highlighted by the +1 in my reputation tab. I can then check my votes tab and see that the downvotes on the question and the undeleted answers are still listed, but the downvotes on the deleted answers have vanished. From that observation I've inferred the difference in meaning between the two numbers.

Comment: @MarkAmery ok thanks, You may post this as an answer as it's what am looking for so it doesn't get lost within all these comments... this will reduce the question to *how to find the downvotes for the post with negative scores* .. In case you are wrong, a moderator or a member of the SO stuff will correct it.

Comment: By contrast to Temani, by the way, my numbers are 3473 and 5429 - i.e. 36% of posts I downvote get deleted - *half* as many as Temani. @peterh, the sort of crude statistic-driven analysis used in your first comment would suggest my ability to recognise low-quality content is thus drastically worse than Temani's, and maybe I am doing harm and should stop voting. I don't think that's true, and blame different usage patterns - for instance, targeting votes primarily at newly-posted close-worthy questions will yield a far higher deletion rate than downvoting old bad answers on popular questions.

Comment: @MarkAmery Your 3473 and 5439 means only that 38.8% of your up- or downvotes are upvotes. You have no easy way to know, what percentage of the posts you voted down were deleted, because you can't list them. I think the crap percentage of the SE is yet tolerable, and I need to click down only in less than 20% of the cases. If the SE would be so crappy that I should vote down in 90% of the cases, I had long left the site. Btw, are you looking specifically for LQ posts? If I am on the SE, I am looking for HQ posts, I am here to learn (and to teach), and not to vote down...

Comment: @peterh Reread my comments; 3473 and 5429 are not my "up" and "down" stats from the "Votes Cast" section (though my "up" stat is similar, entirely concidentally - it's 3422) but are rather two *different* counts of downvotes shown to me in my profile, one of which includes deleted posts and one of which does not. I *do* have an easy way to tell what proportion of posts I voted down were deleted, now noted in my answer.

Comment: @peterh As for whether I look for bad content, there is a sense in which the answer is "yes": before upvoting answers to any question, I typically commit to reading (and considering voting on) *all* the answers, so that my votes don't unfairly keep an incumbent answer at the top of the list just because I couldn't be bothered to read the superior competitor later on. But since lower-voted competing answers *typically* tend to be crap, that means I spend a lot of time wading through crap, especially on popular questions that have become bad answer magnets.

Comment: @peterh There is, of course, a more usual mechanism by which I'd expect lots of users to disproportionately look at crap content, which is spending lots of time in the close votes review queue. I'd guess that I downvote over 95% of questions and over 60% of their answers that I encounter through that queue. Posts deserving of *upvotes* that can be stumbled upon through that queue, on the other hand, are vanishingly rare. If I spent most of my time doing CV review, my upvote/downvote ratio would be *much* more skewed towards downvotes than it is now.

Comment: So frustrating. You may have found better answers if you'd labelled your types differently, asking for a "red/green" or "type1/type2" ratio rather than a "good/bad" one. Ascribing moral value to the variables seems to have acted for most people like a squirrel to a Pixar dog and they've all run off on the regrettable tangent, leaving behind an interesting question to chase silly metagaming butterflies. Bikeshedding at its worst: can't answer the question, so ignore it and nitpick some imagined slight from the question instead.

Comment: @DewiMorgan Yes I should have done like a previous question(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368277/how-to-get-the-number-of-closure-votes-by-type) Providing some context wasn't a good idea...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well... I like and appreciate the context, personally. It makes the question more interesting, and also allows an answerer to suggest alternative approaches. But yeah, I guess I can understand why people find it more distracting than a colder, more abstract question. Then again... it got the question more attention, so maybe the best answers here are better than it would have had, even if the worst are worse? Hrm, metathinking questioning is hard.

Comment: Theorem: the closer the score is to zero the more efficient the downvote.

Comment: If there's any question that you may be 'wrong' to down vote it, never ever ever ever ever down vote it!

Comment: You can get the information you want from a combination of using the SE API and scraping your profile pages for the questions which you have downvoted. To get a start on this there is the userscript [Get a list of posts you've voted on that have been edited](https://stackapps.com/q/6755), which adds a tab in your profile with the posts you've downvoted that have been edited. You'll need to edit the userscript, but it already accesses the data you desire: the posts you've downvoted and requests data from the SE API about those posts, which will/can have the post's score/upvotes/downvotes/etc.

Comment: @Makyen yes thanks! that's intresting. I was also searching that way but wasn't used to userscript and SE API

Comment: I'm surprised you don't account for posts you downvote getting *edited*.

Comment: In my humble opinion, if the number of down wotes is higher than the number of up votes, then you have to re-think you assesments. It is like in the school, if the teacher gives pupils more negative marks, then positiv, it meams teacher is bad and not the whole class.

Comment: @SewerynHabdank-Wojewódzki a teacher will give negative marks to only his class (a defined set of users) and not the whole school or the whole country, so you cannot compare the job of a teacher with what I do. I will explain it *again*: I am running against all the crappy stuffs in order to downvote/close/delete and I will keep down this because I am on front catching all the questions that are poor and bad. I am doing the cleaning job here to make the site good and allow *you* to find the good stuffs. but you won't understand such thing since you are far from doing any cleaning on the site.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: No, downvoting is not only clean-up. Downvoting has several consequences. Also very negative for the persons, not only for the question. This is very often forgotten. So downvoting shall be done very carefully. Before downvoting, there are other measures to perform, comments, and review suggestions, duplicate proposals.
And again - I think, when reviewer has more downvotes then upvotes, I am really considering to think through own the downvoting strategy.

Comment: @SewerynHabdank-Wojewódzki well, you are judging me without having any information about what I am downvoting and what action I am doing. I think there is no need to argue more with you. Fell free to think that my actions are *bad* and not *done carefully* but I won't do the same because I simply don't see any actions done by you (2 edits, 6 helpful flags, 32 answers ... in 5 years)

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Can you point in my post, where I am judging you? 
I am not very active, because once my question was so much blindly downwoted, that I even cannot repair it and my person was banned. 
I am very sceptic about all this downvoting.

Answer (score 25):

A partial answer: you can find out what proportion of downvotes you cast were on now-deleted posts by comparing the two different downvote counts in your profile. The public one, in the Votes Cast section, includes downvotes on deleted questions...

[image: Screenshot of "Votes Cast" section, showing "5,429 down"]

... whereas the one that only you can see, in the votes/downvote tab, shows only votes on non-deleted posts (a smaller number):

[image: Screenshot of votes/downvote tab, showing "3473 Votes Cast"]

By comparing these two numbers, you can calculate what proportion of posts you downvote get deleted. For instance, if I have 5429 downvotes and 3473 of those are on non-deleted posts, then 5429 - 3473 = 1956 of posts I've downvoted have been deleted, which is equal to 1956/5429 = 36% of my downvotes.

Of course, like many commenters on the question, I fundamentally disagree with the premise that only downvotes that ultimately result in deletion or a negative score are "good" downvotes. I don't spend much time in the trash fires that are the front page or the close vote review queue, but I *do* frequently downvote old, highly-upvoted content that I come across through Google and recognise to be incorrect even though many previous voters did not. That means my downvotes will surely have a low "efficiency" per the metric in the question, but I don't think it makes them less correct or less useful than they would be if I spent my time downvoting garbage questions from the CV queue.

Comment: `I fundamentally disagree with the premise that only downvotes that ultimately result in deletion or a negative score are "good" downvotes.` --> I myself disagree about this [I said this in the question as a small note]. I only used the term of *good downvote* for the purpose of this question to define the information I want to gather. Good/bad remains opinion based and no one can define what should be *good* and what should be *bad*

Comment: Sometimes I find questions with 10 similar answers, where the answerers are regularly *racing* to formulate a popular, but false delusion more clearly. And then... I vote them all down. But it is rare. I simply can't find too much bad posts, because I am not looking for them. I am looking for an answer to my question, or I am looking for good quality, well-answerable questions. Both deserve up from me.

Comment: _"`else is` statement"_ Nice

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah. The three titles visible in the screenshot all come from a recent (and uncharacteristic - I usually find it too soul-destroying) bout of reviewing. Two out of three titles being incomprehensible due to broken English is pretty representative of the quality level that one can expect from question titles in the Close Votes review queue, in my experience.

Comment: @MarkAmery I voluntarily surrendered my Close Votes review queue passport some time ago. Soul destroying indeed!

Comment: @peterh and **I** am looking for bad posts to downvote them in order to make it easier for **you** to better find the good quality ones. So I am doing the cleaning job here and I will continue cleaning(downvoting/deleting/closing) as much as possible to get rid of all the crappy stuffs here.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It would be a nice and an acceptable argument... if I could forget what happened to my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45818964/1783163) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40636618/1783163) questions. Why is it that after many years of avid SE usage, I feel myself still *deterred* from asking questions. What did these wonderful "cleaners" think as they voted my these questions down... no, your argument is likely true in many cases, but I am sure, these cases are only a minority. I can imagine that you are not evil, but yes, most of the 1k up / 10k down guys, are evil.

Comment: FWIW, @peterh, I share your sense that asking questions is an unfair minefield. I am far more liberal than most of the Meta crowd when it comes to what kinds of questions we should accept, and I've been reduced to despair on a few occasions trying in vain to save questions I felt were valuable from obliteration. I wish, in general, that we focused more on "is this question useful to future readers?" and less on "can this question be construed to violate one of our many vague and sometimes contradictory rules written in the Help Center or on Meta?". But I don't think vote count tells us much.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What you did? You simply stopped to make VtC reviews?

Comment: @peterh That's right

Comment: @TemaniAfif Your first comment on this answer seems to contradict what you say in the Question: `But if a post will end with a positive score, I was probably wrong downvoting it.` This is not necessarily true. Good/bad downvotes are not  (very?) subjective because the site gives explicit instruction and guidance on when to upvote or downvote. (This isn't reddit or imgur, where you're intended to vote however you personally want to.)

Comment: @KeithM because I simply defined a set of data and I wasn't giving a universal definition about what is good or bad and I wasn't aiming to debate about it. 80% of people here aren't understanding the purpose of my question: I gave a context by defining few things in order to better explain the data I am looking for. It's like I told you *a good person is a person who wake up early* and a *bad person is a person who wake up late* then I need to know how many good person and bad peson we have. I need the data, I don't need to know if what I defined is accurate or has a meaning.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Then you shouldn't call it "good" or "bad", but something else. The definitions of good and bad downvotes already exist; they're defined by the site.

Comment: @KeithM I though it was clear: I start by defining what is *good* then asked how to caclulate it but unfortunately everyone jumped on that definition arguing it's a wrong one ... well, it was too late to edit when I notice all this

Comment: @TemaniAfif In the future, might I suggest using terms "cromulent" and "uncromulent" instead of "good" and "bad"?  Or some other opaque term that doesn't carry baggage?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont yes good idea but next time I will make it a *boring* math question using `X`, `Y` `α`, etc

Comment: @TemaniAfif You will probably also need σ

Comment: I'm at 37%, with 25k downvotes. good 'nuff

Answer (score 5):

To some degree there is no "right" or "wrong" voting. You vote however you think is right, and the *collective voting result* is what counts. In a democracy, not everyone needs to be of the same opinion. That's why *everybody* votes, not just one person. If *you* genuinely think something is worth downvoting, and a handful of others think the opposite, then *the community as a whole* has judged the post to be worthwhile, even if not every single individual member thought so.

And overall, that's a good thing. Not to politicise this, but both "sides" need to be in constant communication with each other to arrive at the best compromise for everyone. That's simply how this works.

Comment: Yes and no. Just like in politics, you should always consider if what you vote still makes sense and not just vote that way because you have done so in the past. Educate yourself! (And that's exactly what op is doing, right?)

Comment: Yeah, again, both sides need to communicate. If standards have shifted, that must be worked out amongst the community. In fact, even without that, your voting behaviour probably drifts over time no matter what. You need to constantly reevaluate yourself to figure out whether you're still in harmony with the rest of the community, and why you mightn't be, and what should be done about it. That still means you cast every single vote according to your conscience in that moment.

Comment: `That still means you cast every single vote according to your conscience in that moment` this is what I do and at some level I don't care about the community votes BUT I described a situation in order to highlight some data and see if I am able to get them. Is simply gave some signification wording like *good downvotes* and *efficiency* to make it clear what I am looking for. I am simply curious to see if such data exists and also curious to know the meaning of the numbers in my profile because I am not able to understand them.

Comment: Does not address the question asked.

Comment: Just hoping to communicate that I don't really find anything of substance in this answer. There is a proper way to vote, which is based on content. This is not a democracy. Just because a post is upvoted doesn't make it correct or even worthwhile, even if a majority upvote it; there are plenty of highly upvoted deleted posts. There also should not be constant communication about voting. I mean, really, nothing here is "how this works", that's not how any of this works.