# Can I see what happened to my votes? e.g. was a question closed when I voted to do it?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Can I see what happened to my votes? e.g. was a question closed when I voted to do it?

I am trying to identify duplicates, but I am not sure if it is worth the effort.
So I would like to see if any of my votes actually resulted successfully closing a question.

Comment: You could look in the votes->closure "tab" in your profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7919597/joe?tab=votes&sort=closure

Comment: The profile only shows which votes I casted, not ŵhat happened to the question. I will search for a query.

Comment: @Joe It's an indication at least, since you will also see if the question you voted on is currently closed or not.

Comment: SEDE can do this, you can grab the question that are closed and where you are involved

Comment: @TemaniAfif you might need to also make sure to go through the history. It's possible that a question *was* closed due to a vote you were involved in but later reopened. And maybe even closed again.

Comment: Argh, can't they just display a small colored circle or the like beside the question in Profile - Votes... ? :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif but votes are anonymous in SEDE. You have no way to find the posts you voted on unless you leave a comment, make an edit or favorite them.

Comment: @rene I think it's about close vote here not downvote/upvote. You helped me before in [a similar task](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368277/8620333). I guess if he's able to fetch the data inside the banner of closed questions he can at least have the number of questions closed (and the list of the questions) then he compare with the total number of votes he gave.

Answer (score 1):

In the Stack Exchange Data Explorer you can only see what happened with your close votes if a post reached that final state, and then only for non-deleted posts. Alternatively you can keep an eye on the reviews you've done and how others reviewed the same post. And there some chatrooms that are open to discuss or ask advice if you have questions around curation and moderation.

For the reviewing history that you can use a script I wrote: [Adding the consensus to review's history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history/251508#251508)

For SEDE  you can find your name in the PostHistory table in rows with typeid = 10 (closed). The Text column will have a JSON with all the voters involved in closing the question.

I've created this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1347012?UserId=7919597) to shows the known events you were involved in:

```
select postid as [Post Link]
     , pht.Name
     , creationdate
from posthistory ph
inner join posthistorytypes pht on pht.id = ph.posthistorytypeid
cross apply openjson(text, '$.Voters') 
   with (
     VoterId Int '$.Id', 
     DisplayName nvarchar(200) '$.DisplayName'
   ) voters 
where ph.posthistorytypeid in (10,11,12,13,14,15,19,20,35)
and len(text) >0
and voters.VoterId = ##userid?7919597##
```

When run today this is the result:

[image: sede result]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the very useful [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the awesome [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).