# How many duplicates have I found so far?

Tags: support, feature-request, duplicate-questions

Now that efforts are underway to [reward duplicate finders](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394048/6574038), how may we find out how much duplicates we have successfully  closed/close-voted so far?

I've tried [this solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368292/6574038), but it doesn't seem to work (anymore):

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: @rene It shows just zero (see added screenshot), but I found a few more.

Comment: Okay, I found the issue, the close reasons got an overhaul and that query doesn't handle that nicely. Working on a fix now

Comment: another generic query that gives stat of all users: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1237407/dupe-hammer-accuracy .. you can easily update to get only your stat by adding a simple `where hc.UserId = ..`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1245768?UserId=6574038) that shows you how often you found a duplicate that lead to the actual closure of the question with that reason. This only counts non-deleted posts and doesn't take re-openings into account. The count is split between "normal" duplicates and duplicates where you "hammered" a question due to a gold badge you own.

The PostHistory table in SEDE records in rows with PostHistoryTypeid = 10 the close event of a question. In the text column a JSON object is stored that holds the questionid and the close voters. With the SQL function JSON_Value you can parse and select properties out of that JSON text. Given there are in theory at most 5 close voters (but some cases exist where 6 or even 7 close voters are found) we can cross join with a set of numbers from 1 till 7 to get the individual close vote userid's.

```sql
select hammertag
     , count(*) [#duplicates]
from
(
select JSON_value(text, concat(N'$.Voters[', value, N'].Id')) userid
     , JSON_value(text, concat(N'$.Voters[', value, '].BindingReason.GoldTagBadge')) hammertag
from posthistory ph
cross join string_split(N'0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7',',')
where ph.posthistorytypeid = 10 -- closed 
and comment in (1,101) -- duplicate close reasons
and JSON_value(text, concat(N'$.Voters[', value, N'].Id')) = '##userid:int?6574038##'
) data
group by hammertag
```

When run today, this is the result for your account:

[image: sede result showing 78 regular duplicates and 10 dupe-hammer duplicates in the R tag]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Give a big shout-out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) she wrote.
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: why your query is giving me more than 4000 while this one (https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1237407/dupe-hammer-accuracy) is giving me around 3700 ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif that query only looks at the new close reason (ids > 100) My query also takes the previous close reasons into account. Id's 1 and 101 are the ones to be taken into account.

Comment: an idea when the change from old to new was made? I guess I was not yet here because I don't remember seeing close reasons like *Too localized*

Comment: @TemaniAfif 6 to 8 years ago https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons

Comment: @rene Do that query work correctly given that mods have a built in hammer?

Comment: @DavidPostill it will record that you dupe voted having a goldbadge. The bindingreason is there. When you dupe vote "regular" questions it isn't indicated you did so as mod. I can tell you are a mod due to  you being the only close voter but that is about it.

Comment: @DavidPostill here is a query that is the best I can do to show a diamond vote, regular vote or tag gold badge vote: https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/1245928?UserId=337631

Comment: Neat. Thanks... total matches as well :)