# How can I find questions voted to close by me with a specific close reason?

Tags: support

I want to see questions with [my close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr?tab=votes) filtered by "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" reason. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the number of closure votes by type?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368277/how-to-get-the-number-of-closure-votes-by-type) (you can probably edit the query to get the link of questions instead of the count)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, there is no reason "not reproducable" and results count is less than 500 (why?). I don't know how to get links. I wanted to check last few questions where I voted "caused by typo".