# Should "duplicate" and "closed" attributes be added to the answer log in user profile?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, quality-improvement

When browsing my answer log there aren't any `[duplicate]`s visible.

However, a question I answered recently was closed as a duplicate, and this is not visible in my answer log.

In OP's question log it says:

[image]

In my answers, however, the title does not seem to be updated:

[image]

This is probably the same with `[closed]` attributes.

Would it be possible to also update the answer log to have better control over which questions we answered were closed as duplicates or whatever?

The quality of the website would be improved by allowing users to better assess their own answering behavior. However, if someone else is looking through your answering log, the attributes will also appear, which may displease some users and may therefore be worth discussing.

Comment: In OP **question** log ... in my **answers**.. Questions and answers are different things, this is why you don't see duplicated or closed in your answers. How exactly seeing if you answered to a closed question improves the quality? Do you have a scenario in head where it will be useful? I guess you could ask for that and you may likely get the answer with SEDE query (though sometimes the answers are [not helpful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401417/1997232)).

Comment: @Sinatr I guess being able to check that question was closed as duplicate could help build up duplicate base, so that you won't answer such questions in future. But I don't see myself going this far to avoid accidentally answering a duplicate.

Comment: You start to get a"feel" of what is (and isn't) a duplicate as you answer more and more questions in a tag, rather than reviewing your past answers anyway, @Yksisarvinen . It's more something you learn over time and with experience than looking for information on. There are, however, some questions you will likely learn very quickly are duplicates for specific tags, as there are 2 or more questions asking the same thing every day. *Though I know of some users who are very active in tags and appear to have a nasty allergy to the "Close as Duplicate" feature.*

Comment: @Sinatr if I had an answer on a duplicate, I'd probably want to move my answer to the canonical and delete it on the duplicate.

Comment: You can use this SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/147801/find-closed-answers-by-user

Comment: It's always such a drag to find out it my Answer is keeping a Question from being Roomba'ed. It would be nice to get that on the list. Then at least I can evaluate if I should just delete my Answer and let the post go or move my Answer to a duplicate target, or check the target to see if my Answer is too similar to an existing Answer.

Comment: @Scratte I don't know if that's good practice. We know that we are not supposed to use (abuse) downvotes to trigger roomba. I don't know if deleting our answers would be the same or not, but needs a little more thought/discussion before commuting to doing so. p.s. what you added as an edit to your comment makes it more appealing.

Comment: I created a user script that does this. Find it at [Answer link titles in user profiles deserves closed status too](https://stackapps.com/questions/9086/answer-link-titles-in-user-profiles-deserves-closed-status-too)

Answer (score 4):

> When browsing my answer log there aren't any [duplicate]s visible.
>
> However, a question I answered recently was closed as a duplicate, and this is not visible in my answer log.

**Your answer wasn't marked as a duplicate — the question was**. Hence why the question is tagged as [duplicate] and your answer is not.

Now, some of your answers may be —and, given the sheer number of answers in SO, they most probably are— "duplicates" of some other answers, in the SO sense that they are more or less saying the same thing; but that's OK for answers! Answering with the same solution explained in a different way might help different people with different backgrounds and levels of understanding.

Not so much for questions, where the goal is to lay out the details of a problem clearly enough for experts to be able to give a solution. There's no need to target different people here — asking the *same* question in different ways will only lead to the *same* people answering again.

Comment: But asking the same question in a different way will sometimes help search engines find the question when it's worded drastically different to the other one.  This happens frequently when there's a special term that describes the problem but isn't known by the asker.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, that's why duplicates are just marked as such, instead of deleted: to keep the benefits of multiple search results while avoiding the problem of the same people having to write the same answers again and again.

Comment: It's not uncommon for closed questions to be deleted automatically by the Roomba.

Comment: @MarkRansom Indeed — as long as they fit the criteria explained in https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba, which for duplicates can be summed up as "remove duplicates that are no longer serving their purpose". As a user with 250k+ rep like you probably knows, there are lots of duplicates several years old that still attract visits, and so remain undeleted. Still not sure what any of this has to do with _answers_, though.

Comment: The whole premise of this question is to discover which of your answers are in danger of being deleted, which they will be when the question is deleted.

Comment: @MarkRansom AFAIK, duplicates with answers are not deleted.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  I thought it required that the question or answer have a positive vote score.

Comment: @MarkRansom As per the Roomba help page, duplicates are subject to the same rules as other posts, except for the "9 days ago"-rule. Which seems to indicate that just one Answer will keep it from being Roomba'ed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see much positive use of this feature - discounting the ability to answer-shame users for poor answering habits. We already have a tool for that - vote, vote and vote. Don't be afraid to downvote a bad answer (so long as you're voting on the content, not the user).

As for the argument of this being useful to refer back to duplicates, you can bookmark/star questions which achieves the same purpose.

Comment: Why would one want to bookmark a post that one have an Answer to? I also think you missed the point. It's on one's own Answer list that there's no mention of the status of the post. So going through that list, one cannot see that one has Answered a post that was subsequently closed.

Comment: @Scratte why not? There could be multiple reasons, including saving it for duplicate marking later. I understood that the OP is calling for adding status tags to the answer, but those status tags apply to the _question_, not the answer. Votes (and IMO reacts) should theoretically be the only way to determine answer quality. You can still write a great answer to a bad question, so such signals are not useful in my opinion.

Comment: The status applies to the title of the post that the Answer is on. The Answer doesn't have a title at all. If I want to know if I've posted Answers on post that were later closed, I have to go through all my Answers and check the Question. That's not very user friendly. It's also not very use friendly to force me to put all those in my bookmarks, since I wish to use the bookmarks for posts that I do **not** have Answers on. Bookmarks are my todo list / problem post list / canonical list.

Comment: "I'm curious to see if the question is closed" is not convincing enough a reason to propose this feature request. I'd like to know what benefits you foresee with such a feature, I would welcome your reply in answer form to this Meta question. @Scratte Also re:bookmarking, imo having questions of interest in a short list that is easily accessible is far more user friendly than trawling through an endless list of answers, especially if you (like me) have thousands of them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't Answer posts on meta anymore, @cs95. I did just make another comment on the Question though. But do you want to go through your thousand Answers one by one to check if you should remove your Answer? :)