# Please, add closed typo questions to Roomba!

Tags: feature-request, automatic-deletion, typographical-error

Well, the title says everything and I know [there are other questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273266/8620333) around but I still want to revive this subject again in a hope things will change.

Typo questions attract easy answers within a few minutes (easy Reputation), the question is up-voted (by people answering it) and even the answers are up-voted (by the OP).

I have been around for a long time to notice that typo questions get more attention with all the answers and up-votes than the *real* questions but they are **useless, off topic, and not helpful to the community**. They are only helpful to the person who asked the question (and got his answer).

### Let's add them to the Roomba

Comment: My issue with this is i don't trust the community to use the typo close reason correctly.  

I've seen enough "typo" questions that are actually common syntax problem that are useful to beginners.

Comment: @psubsee2003 if a post is incorrectly closed, it can be reopened before roomba reaches it. if it doesn't... and it's such a common case, it *will* be asked again.

Comment: @psubsee2003 *questions that are actually common syntax problem that are useful to beginners* --> those are in 99.99% of the cases duplicate questions. All beginner questions are most likely to be duplicate unless it's about new technologies or new langagues (which is not the case for CSS, C++, PHP, Java, and so on)

Comment: i disagree.  Once closed, it is harder to reopen.  And I still don't trust the community to handle typo closures correctly

Comment: I similarly don't trust users to accurately determine that something isn't a typo. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ both are solved by just nuking it and letting it be reasked in a better form.

Comment: if a question is *incorrectly* closed as a typo and so not useful/borderline that it can't attract reopen votes, we aren't losing anything from it's deletion.

Comment: I have mixed feelings here.  On the one hand, I totally don't trust people not to misuse that close reason.  On the other hand...ehhh, they can already do most of the damage already in terms of subjecting questions to roomba/delete votes by misusing it, and with sufficiently specific criteria like "typos with <0 score are deleted after 90 days" we could probably delete most of the useless stuff with very little loss of useful material.

Comment: @RyanM exactly! I don't want to have nuclear-roomba for them. Even 180 days is good. It doesn't matter how long they last as long as they are deleted. People will stop answering them when they will see their reputation gone. Including them in Roomba will discourage people from answering them knowing it's useless (especially users that are here for the Rep)

Comment: Temani, I'd suggest to add your point on the long roomba period (you suggested 180 days) into your question post. If you do, I'll +1. No need to notify me if you do. I'm following this post.

Comment: @user I don't really want to be specific. I want the feature to be considered and the community to find the best criteria for the roomba. If you agree on number of days or you have a better criteria consider adding it as an answer so people can interact with it.

Comment: I guess one of the possible problems with this feature request is that staff has to create a new algorithm for site-specific Roomba since there is no "typo" close reason on other SE sites...

Comment: I was going to try to get some stats on this, but [apparently it's not possible to query which off-topic reason was used to close a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297750/165261).

Comment: @AndrewT. That sounds like a really minor inconvenience. Maybe I’m wrong, but it doesn’t sound like more than max 20 lines of code should be necessary for that.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship just giving my opinion based on years of experience in doing meta...

Comment: @AndrewT. Won’t they have to make the change no matter how much work it is, though?

Comment: @AndrewT. Rep is kept, if the post had score of 3 and more and has been visible for at least 60 days. If they managed to get 3 upovtes, they would keep it, if it gets deleted after 180 days.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship HAH [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20%5bfeature-request%5d%20or%20%5bbug%5d%20-%5bstatus-completed%5d%20-%5bstatus-by-design%5d%20-%5bstatus-declined%5d&searchOn=3) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20%5bfeature-request%5d%20or%20%5bbug%5d%20-%5bstatus-completed%5d%20-%5bstatus-by-design%5d%20-%5bstatus-declined%5d&searchOn=3)

Comment: @gre_gor not sure if you intended to reply to my comment about the "new algorithm" or to someone else (perhaps [Temani's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424664/please-add-closed-typo-questions-to-roomba#comment957496_424664) about "rep loss"?), but what I meant was: currently, all Roomba criteria are generic and universal to all SE sites. If this request will be implemented, then the staff has to create a new algorithm on *their source code* for allowing Roomba customization *per-site* (another thing is, how broad is the customization?), which AFAIK is a completely new featur

Comment: @TemaniAfif "those are in 99.99% of the cases duplicate questions." - the problem is, there will *commonly* be *dozens* of duplicates that are *all bad*, because every single one is asked by a beginner with no understanding of anything relevant. Identifying the common thread requires a specialized skill: an experienced user who not only can *notice the pattern* of many beginners making the same *kind of* mistake, but also *fathom how* beginners can all think in the same misguided way, and create a canonical Q&A. Even then, you still have to advertise and use the canonical.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am not saying they are good. Those duplicates are also a problem but I can easily handle them alone. I have closed more than 6000 question as duplicates and If I do this fast enough we avoid the repeated answers and the redirection will do its job (in case the question is not deleted). Even if there is no redirection, the user is obliged to look at the duplicate to get the answer. I still hope we can clean many of them but it's not a big issue compared to typo questions.

Answer (score 8):

It'd be nice to get some data on

- Questions closed as Typo / Not Reproducible that also have answers that block them from getting auto-deleted

  1. To see the scale of the problem
  2. To see the distribution of how long ago these questions were closed
- Questions that weren't closed, but with close votes or flags using this close-reason that aged away and without any "Leave Open" reviews. (Since the close-vote queue is "understaffed").
- Questions that were closed as Typo / Not Reproducible and later re-opened, and how long it took the re-opening to happen. (to inform how long we might want the Roomba to wait before deleting these)

At the moment, we can't query SEDE for specific off-topic close reasons ([see this feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297750/997587)). If we wanted that data, I think we'd need to ask for staff support.

Comment: I once wanted such information too: [How to get the number of closure votes by type?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368277/8620333)

Answer (score -4):

Counter-proposal:

When a question is closed as typo, do not award points for up votes, edits, etc. on the question or answers. That seems like the appropriately gamified way to deal with the "people answering garbage for imaginary internet points instead of moderating" phenomenon. Should the question be reopened, points can be retroactively rewarded.

(You could take this to its natural extreme and not award points for all interactions with questions that eventually get closed; maybe that would convince people not to polish turds or answer duplicate questions. I'd lose about half my rep, but at this point I think i really wouldn't mind if it helped with the overall quality of this site.)

Comment: I don't want to deal with people answering the question and their Rep, I want the question to **not exist** and be **deleted**. Even if the system keeps all the Rep and delete the question, I will be fine with it.

Comment: 1/3 your post is about how people use these bad questions to farm easy rep; removing the rep will discourage that behavior.

Comment: Isn’t that exactly what deletion achieves? What other reason is there to keep an off-topic, unlikely-of-Future-use question than to preserve votes?

Comment: The community [already decided](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384463/are-questions-about-code-published-in-a-book-exclusions-from-the-general-off-top) that not all typo questions are off topic and some shouldn't even be closed.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas A typo question that isn’t off-topic (because it is useful in the future) shouldn’t be closed - the close reason even points that out. The two features are basically equivalent. This meta-question is about  those that do not fall into that category.

Answer (score -23):

You're implicitly trusting that someone accurately closed a question as a typo, though.  That's *subjective* data in which some close voter could easily make a mistake. The majority could make the mistake.  Everyone could make the mistake.

The data points the Roomba operates on are *objective* in that they are explicit values and explicit timings.

Comment: This is 100% correct.  Close reasons are a mess.  you can't just subject them to the roomba because you don't like the type of question.

Comment: not someone but 3 users. Worth noting that Typo question are already considered in Roomba when it has no answer and a negative score. So many questions mistakenly closed can be deleted (not only typo question)

Comment: @psubsee2003 in such case, let's disable Roomba from all the questions because I can easily find 2 friends to rapidly close the questions I don't like, downvote them and they are good for Roomba (let's not forget that I can close them alone with my gold hammer). You argument doesn't really stand here.

Comment: @TemaniAfif:  [You *yourself* can't action all of these criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions).  You can simply be the catalyst to a decent amount of them.  (Then, you'll be on the hook for the voting discrepancies.)

Comment: Without taking a position on the overall issue, I disagree with the underlying characterization in this answer that there's a subjective/objective difference between the reason for closure and other primary Roomba criteria. The Roomba tasks which aren't related to migration *all* have a criteria that the question score must be at or below 0 or -1. That's as subjective as it gets, and often comes down to a single person voting up/down. I agree that it's certainly possible for "typo" to be the wrong reason for question closure, but it's not more subjective than, potentially, a single vote.

Comment: In addition to Makyen's excellent points about voting being taken into account, and also without taking a position on the overall issue, this objection could apply to _any_ closure.  Roomba takes closures into account, and questions can be closed that should not have been closed.  Closure itself is no more subjective or objective than the reason selected.

Comment: Aside from that, *there is already precedent* for the Roomba caring about closure reason. In particular, duplicates cannot be "abandoned closed".

Comment: The same argument applies for other roomba tasks. I can single-handedly delete zero-scored unanswered questions that are a month old just by downvoting them.